# The JDBC sink connector encountered a null key and null key schema error while configuring the postgres-kafka CDC platform

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, cdc

I'm new to Kafka, so I don't know much about it.
I wanted to copy all the tables in the 'ddm' schema from the Postgresql database to another PostgreSQL.
Dozens of topics were created using the debezium source connector for dozens of tables in Postgresql's ddm schema.
I tried to group these topics into one sink connector and mirror them to another Postgresql.

```
#source connector
{
        "name":"source-ai-ddm",
        "config":{
                "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
                "table.include.list": "ddm.*",
                "database.user": "postgres",
                "database.dbname": "ai",
                "slot.name": "omni_channel",
                "topic.prefix": "ai-ddm",
                "database.server.name": "dbserver3",
                "database.port": "5432",
                "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
                "database.hostname": "localhost",
                "database.password": "password",
                "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
                "transforms": "unwrap",
        }
}
```

```
{
        "name": "sink-ai-ddm",
        "config": {
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
                "tasks.max": "1",
                "topics.regex": "ai.ddm.*",
                "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://10.50.1.38:5432/postgres",
                "connection.user" :"postgres",
                "connection.password" : "postgres",
                "dialect.name": "PostgreSqlDatabaseDialect",
                "transforms": "unwrap,route",
                "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
                "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
                "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite",
                "transforms.route.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
                "transforms.unwrap.add.fields":"op,schema",
                "transforms.route.regex": "ai.ddm.(.*)",
                "transforms.route.replacement": "$1",
                "insert.mode": "upsert",
                "delete.enabled": "true",
                "auto.create": "true",
                "auto.evolve": "true",
                "pk.mode": "record_key",
                "delete.retention.ms":"100"
        }
}
```

These connectors worked well in a schema where all the primary keys were present. But not in ddm skima.

The source connector executed well and generated the topic normally. However, the following error occurs on the sink connector.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'sink-ai-ddm' is configured 
with 'delete.enabled=true' and 'pk.mode=record_key' and therefore requires records with a non-null
 key and non-null Struct or primitive key schema, but found record at 
(topic='ddm.t_part_record',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1680680464588) with a null key and null key 
schema.\n\tat 
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.RecordValidator.lambda$requiresKey$3(RecordValidator.java:116)\n\tat 
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:81)\n\tat 
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:74)\n\tat 
io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:85)\n\tat 
org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:581)\n\t... 10 
more\n"}],"type":"sink"}
```

In my estimation, it is a problem caused by the absence of a primary key in some tables in the schema to be replicated.
When I checked the kafka message on the topic about the table that had an error, there was no Key.

I tried changing "pk.mode": "record_key" to "pk.mode": "record_value" but failed.

My situation is as follows.

1. I can't specify the primary key by modifying the table.
2. Too many tables. So you want to configure and manage connectors on a schema basis.
3. I'm trying to organize including a table without a primary key.

Is it possible to solve this error?
Or is there another more efficient way?
I'm having a hard time because I don't have much information about my situation. Please help me